# R - Pie, X values must be positive

Tags: r

I am new to R and drew some testdata about countries in a csv from the web. I am currenty fooling arround with plotting and encountered said error while creating a pie chart of the worlds unemployment.

i issued the following:

```
>values <- read.csv("D:\\test\\countrydata.csv")
>names(values)
 [1] "name"    "size"    "pop"    "unemployed" ...
>typeof(values$unemployed)
"integer"
>pie(values$pop)
Error in pie(values$unemployed) :
    'x' values must be positive
>pie(values$pop, na.rm=TRUE)
Error in pie(values$unemployed, na.rm=TRUE) :
    'x' values must be positive
```

The dataset i want to plot is a set of integers, all of them are positive, 0 (thanks kim) or NA.

0 are not a problem when plotting integers, i tried

```
>pie(as.integer(c(0,1,2,3))
```

and it worked fine.

What am i missing here?

Thanks and Regards,

BillDoor

Comment: Weird. You do `pie(values$pop)` and the error message says `Error in pie(values$unemployed)`? You want a pie chart of `pop` and the error says `unemployed`? Really?

Comment: problem comes from `NA`values. Try `pie(as.integer(c(0,1,2,3,NA)))`, you'll get the same error... (and there is no `na.rm` parameter in pie function...)

Comment: ...and there is no `na.rm=TRUE` argument to `pie`. And because `pie` slurps up unmatched arguments as graphics parameters, it doesn't treat that as an error. Lesson: just because one R function has a useful `na.rm` argument, doesn't mean they all have. Don't expect consistency in R, always read the documentation!

Comment: the $pop is a copy error, because i, while writting this question, tried another set, first try was with pop

Comment: Never ever **EVER** make a pie chart. Please read some Ed Tufte

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't have access to your data but in my experience the following might help and is definitely worth a try:

```
pie(table(values$unemployed))
```

Would love to learn whether this solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

According to the R documentation, the first argument must be **"non-negative vector"** Now when we write
`pie(value$pop)`
Then R considers it as a numeric data frame which you can check by
`str(value$pop).`
When you typecast via as.numeric or as.integer, you convert it to a vector, that's why it works on typecasting:
`pie(as.numeric(value$pop))`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem. Here's what worked for me:

vectorVal <- as.numeric(table)
pie(vectorVal)

Comment: A 'first answer'! Good job. The answer you provided places two separate commands on one line, which would be invalid syntax in R. Make sure you double check your solution to ensure that it prints accurately. Perhaps use code blocks? Also, please provide additional guidance to the OP as to why your answer solves the problem. Again, thanks for contributing to the SO community - your help is always appreciated.